# Start android app with voice command

Tags: android, speech-recognition, broadcastreceiver

I want to launch my service with a voice command like the name of the app. Is it possible? Can I listen for such an event?

Comment: @josilber thanks for editing my 5 years old question again and again. One day it will be the perfect question (or you will find a job and stop editing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to be listening all the time, but you can do an app or perhaps a widget to use the [speech input api](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/03/speech-input-api-for-android.html) and send an [intent](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/Intent.html) with the text gathered.

Comment: i knew i was asking too much from android sdk :) thanks for the answer. i didn't know internet was needed for speech recog.

Answer (score 0):

Google has introduced a new voice interaction API you can check that here, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OW1A4XFRuyc&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIJDPXCTt5TLDu67271PruEk